# What's the best way to monitor a Reddit submission for new/edited comments?

Tags: python, rest, oauth, reddit, praw

I'm making a website that allows users to submit a single post to multiple social media platforms, and track how those posts perform across those platforms.

Currently I use an authenticated instance of PRAW to poll Reddit every so often and fetch all the comments, using something like this:

```
r = get_authorized_praw_instance(my_user_id)
link = r.submission(id = database.get_link())
link.comments.replace_more(limit = None) # This line places a LOT of requests
for comment in link.comments.list():
  store_the_comment(comment)
```

This is quite expensive though, and I'd rather not brute-force my way through updating my local cache.

Is there another way to do this? Perhaps I could poll a certain endpoint and request all new/edited comments from after a certain timestamp?

Comment: Depending on the subreddit, you could stream comments in the subreddit and ignore all but the ones that are on the post you care about. [This tutorial](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/reply_bot.html) walks you through the basics of PRAW streams, if you don't already know.

Comment: Worth noting that this would require actively monitoring the subreddits for all posts you care about. So you wouldn't be able to update, say, one an hour, and just catch up all at once.